# PyInstaller Hidden Imports Param for Local Imports

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, python-module

(Open to suggestions for a more descriptive title)

I am trying to package my script using Pyinstaller and get the following when trying to run the exe:

```
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "apryse_sdk\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "PDFNetPython3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PDFNetPython'
```

The import in the main script that solicits this error looks like:

```
from apryse_sdk import *
```

where the associated `__init__.py` contains the nested import:

```
...
from PDFNetPython import *
```

Notice that here `PDFNetPython` is imported locally. See the file structure:

```
 Directory: C:\Program Files\Anaconda2022\Lib\site-packages\apryse_sdk


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         9/11/2023  12:56 PM                __pycache__
-a----          9/7/2023   1:13 PM       45508632 PDFNetC.dll
-a----          9/7/2023   1:13 PM             12 PDFNetPyLibInfo
-a----          9/7/2023   1:13 PM         658347 PDFNetPython.py
-a----          9/7/2023   1:13 PM        7536128 _PDFNetPython.pyd
-a----         9/11/2023   1:33 PM            474 __init__.py
```

I keep seeing that the syntax for the `--hidden-import` param is just `--hidden-import=<Module>` but does this apply to local imports? It doesn't seem to me that it does. What is the workaround?

Comment: you have to try 2 solutions .... 1- it is updating your python version to the newest version of python .... 2-if it still appears you should take the library and put it next to your program and merge it with it , to be able to import it from the app files

Comment: if you did the solution number 2 and i see that you did it and the problem still appears then you have to see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741

Comment: @Pythoner-sh Updating python version isn't an option for me. So by "merge" do you mean to add the site-package directory (`apryse_sdk`) as an argument to the `--add-data=` parameter?

Comment: to make it simple on you you should try "auto-py-to-exe" library. take a look at it, it is like a helper to customize and deal with pyinstaller in a GUI and if you want to merge the library you can easily do it through it. https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ ... i mean by "merge"  that you can take the library and put it in the same path with your code and add it as a folder using pyinstaller to make your program able to see the library when it works

Comment: and about updating, try to install new version of python without editing your old python and try to run your code with the new version and convert it into exe. as a try

Comment: @Pythoner-sh Ok "merging" worked but I really want the "onefile" - is there a way to create the onefile from the folder?

Comment: do you mean that you want to make your application as a onefile ?

Comment: @Pythoner-sh Yes, and I was able to get that working (turns out when I thought it wasn't working, it is actually because I have so many imports that initialization takes forever). However, now I run into the following problem (which is related to your 2nd comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77092427/pyinstaller-cant-os-path-join-with-sys-meipass

Comment: now does your code work and every thing great ?

Comment: @Pythoner-sh Yes everything works now, thanks! So the solution was just to add the module with `--add-data` (if you want to create an answer I'll accept it)

Comment: You Are Welcome .... yes i have written an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to try 2 solutions ....

1- it is updating your python version to the newest version of python ....

2-if it still appears you should take the library and put it next to your program and merge it with it , to be able to import it from the app files

what do i mean by the choice number 2 ?

i mean that you have to take the library for example this is its name **`the_library`**

and insert or merge it inside the final application that you have by adding this additional command

> --add-data (the path of your library)

this operation will take the library and merge it with the application and make one file normally

also you can add files not only folder using the same command.

and you can `auto-py-to-exe` library to make the merging and adding files or folders into your app more easy.

you can install it by this command

> pip install auto-py-to-exe

after that turn itt on by calling the name only **auto-py-to-exe**

and you can choose your python file and the icon

after that you can choose the files or folders or libraries to add like this:

[image]

and choose your folder that you want to add by **add folder**

[image]

after that you can see the command below and this helper **(auto-py-to-exe)** made this operation easier.

[image]

**Important to mention :**

**Not All The Time You Have To Add Your Libraries Like This .... We Do This When We Face A Problem In Adding It Using PyInstaller**