# PyInstaller: can't os.path.join with sys._MEIPASS

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I found a snippet online that demonstrates how to retrieve the temporary folder PyInstaller unpacks to:

```
try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), ".abc")
```

but I am getting behavior that is strange to me. After this snippet, I do the following:

```
input_path = os.path.join(base_path, "\\TEMP")

print("Environment", os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), ".aft"))
print("Base Path", base_path)
print("Input Path", input_path)
```

which yields:

```
Environment C:\Users\<user>\.abc
Base Path C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI202162
Input Path C:\TEMP
```

Why is the input path merely `C:\TEMP` instead of `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI202162\TEMP`?

Comment: `os.path.join()` ignores any arguments to the left of any argument that isn't relative.  And `\TEMP` isn't relative - it refers to a specific directory on the current drive.  You probably don't want that backslash in front of it.